# Using list of custom Class object as data source for crystal report

Tags: vb.net, class, crystal-reports

I am trying to find way to design a report using my own custom class.

I found links:

1.) [How to work in Crystal Report with Object Data Source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171026/how-to-work-in-crystal-report-with-object-data-source)

2.) [Use .net object as data source in Crystal Report 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818449/use-net-object-as-data-source-in-crystal-report-2008)

3.) [Binding object with List<> to Crystal Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869476/binding-object-with-list-to-crystal-report)

4.) [How to assign Custom class as datasource in crystal report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244711/how-to-assign-custom-class-as-datasource-in-crystal-report)

They were quite helpful, but I have been stuck in the first step while designing report as my custom class's property is not listed in field list of crystal report design view.

Sample of my Custom Class:

```
class UserType
    public property UIN as integer...
    public property Title as string...
end class
class User
    public property UIN as Integer...
    public property Name as string...
    public property Password as String...
    public property Type as UserType...
end class
```

When I add my class objects to crystal report I do not get the usertype field from users class in field list.

So how can I add usertype field to my field list?   Or do I have to take another approach?

**Edit:**

The reason i wanted to use it as i am:
1.) Showing a form where user can type keyword
2.) program filters the records as per keyword using LINQ
3.) when user clicks the print button, I want to set the filtered records as datasource of my report

Answer (score 1):

- Create your dataset with the columns matching your class, and assign
  the dataset to your report normally.
- When you have your object class loaded with data, and/or filtered with values entered by users (filtered with linq etc..)
  do this:

  ```
  dim yourDataset as dataset ' this is your typed dataset
  Dim dr As datarow
  For n As Integer = 0 To yourClass.Count - 1
      dr = yourDataset.tables("TableName").NewRow
      dr("ColumnNameOne") = yourClass(n).PropertyName
      dr("ColumnNameTwo") = yourClass(n).PropertyName

      yourDataset.tables("TableName").Rows.Add(dr)
  Next

  ' bind the datasource
  crystalreport.SetDatasource(ds)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You could try serializing the object to XML, supply an XSD, then use Crystal Report's XML driver to connect to it.  The report will 'see' the object as two tables: one for the User and one for UserType.  You'll include both 'tables' in the report and link the tables using the internal_id field.

Comment: how do we serialize objects to xml in design time? or we do it in runtime?

Comment: To design the report, you can use 'static' XML and XSD documents.  At run time, you can point it to a Url that returns the two documents or use this approach: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/xml/ReportingXMLDataUsingCrystalReportsAndWindowsForms.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you assign a strongly typed dataset to your report and save yourself lots of trouble?

Comment: does that matches my working crteria... can you provide some link?